# How to break on watch variables?

Tags: node.js, node-inspector

I'm writing a simple command-line Node.js application where `GLOBAL.thingies` is ending up `undefined` for me mysteriously.

I used node-inspector, and I can set breakpoints at any given line, and I have "watch expressions" for that variable, like I do in any debugger.  However, I can't find when that expression is becoming `undefined`.  How can I set a breakpoint whenever a variable changes?

Node-inspector version 0.9.2.

Node version 0.12.2

Chrome version 41

Answer (score 1):

I don't think node-inspector has the feature you're asking for.

There are a few typical ways to analyze a problem like this and hopefully find out what's going on.

**Theorize What You're Looking For**

First, make yourself a list of how `GLOBAL.thingies` could be suddenly coming back as `undefined`.  In this particular cause, you'd not only be looking for an assignment to `GLOBAL.thingies`, but also a possible replacement of the whole `GLOBAL` object with a new object that just doesn't have the `thingies` property on it.

**Code Inspection**

1. Do a grep on all code involved in your project and inspect and study any code that is capable of changing your variable.  You will have to be creative with your grep to make sure you include all possible types of references.  In your particular example `GLOBAL.thingies` and `GLOBAL["thingies"]` would be different ways of accessing it.  In this cause, you may just want to search for any possible use of `thingies` or may even want to include all references to `GLOBAL`.
2. At each reference to the code study it and decide if it is a suspect for causing your problem.

**Binary Search with Breakpoints**

1. Identify which high level operation causes the variable to change to the undesired state.
2. Set things up in the debugger so you have a breakpoint at the beginning of that high level operation before the variable has changed.
3. Step through the top level actions in that high level operation to pin down which action within that operation causes the variable to change.
4. Restart things to get back to where you were in step 2 before the variable changed.  Set a breakpoint right before the top level action that causes the variable to change.  Run to that breakpoint.
5. Now step into that action.  Step over each top level function within the troublesome action until you find which function causes the variable to change.
6. Repeat the process again going down to a finer and finer level of detail until you finally find THE function that causes the variable to change (that doesn't call other functions).  Then step through each line of code in that function to find where it is changing.

In some cases, you can simplifying the scope of the binary search by instrumenting the code with logging statements that log the value of the variable in question so you can more quickly identify when the variable goes from good to bad and what operations that occurs in - limiting the scope of your binary search just to that operation.  If you have lots of async operations in the suspect area (which are much harder to step over) then logging instrumentation is probably required to help you narrow it down to where the problem is occurring.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.  It turns out I was assigning to `thingies` (without the GLOBAL.) at some point, which must be the same object.